# Applications menu is messed up after copying files from old home folder

Tags: applications, pantheon

After copying my files from my old home folder to the new one, the applications menu is now missing categories, and not displaying all installed applications. Is there a config file I should delete somewhere/a way of resetting the applications menu?

Answer (score 0):

GNOME application categories are stored in `/usr/share/desktop-directories/` and in `/home/[your-username]/.local/share/desktop-directories/`.  Try copying the contents of these folders from your old installation to the new one, and see if it helps.

More info on categories available [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435806/how-to-create-a-new-category-in-the-gnome-menu).